# How to let the center div in the mask div align center?

Tags: html, css

How to let the center div in the mask div align center?

the styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .mask {
        position: absolute; top: 0px;
        filter: alpha(opacity=60);
        background-color: #777;
        z-index: 1002; left: 0px;
        opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .center {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

</style>
```

the html:

```
<div id="mask" class="mask">
    <div class="center">MASC</div>
</div>
```

How to let the center div in the mask div align center?

I created a shade layer, and in it there is a div, I want the div align center, but my style code seems not work.

Comment: Specify the width of the center element. The div will occupy the width of the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let you try set position property with the fixed value.

```
.mask {
       position: absolute; top: 0px;
       filter: alpha(opacity=60);
       background-color: #777;
       z-index: 1002; left: 0px;
       opacity:0.5; -moz-opacity:0.5;
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
}

.center {
        position: fixed;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style `text-align: center` to your center div.

```css
<style type="text/css">.mask {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  background-color: #777;
  z-index: 1002;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -moz-opacity: 0.5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, You should specify the width of the `.center` div.

```
.center {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 100px;
}
```

To center the text you can align center

```
.center {
   text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: But it seems only horizon align center, how about the vertical align center?

Comment: There are a lot of techniques on vertical alignment you can check this out 
https://vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/

Answer (score 0):

There are two good choices here:

1.Use table layout

```
.mask{
  display:table;
}
.center{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

2.Use Flex layout

```
.mask{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```